# Reporting Services RangeBar Chart X-Axis labels time portion only of a datetime value

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2008

I have a Business Intelligence project in Visual Studio 2008. I have added a report and placed a RangeBar chart in it. The dataset is as follows:

```
dbName         dbStartTime             dbEndTime               
-------------- ----------------------- ----------------------- 
Unit2-Room2    2009-02-01 09:00:00.000 2009-02-01 13:30:00.000 
Unit2-Room1    2009-02-01 09:00:00.000 2009-02-01 13:00:00.000 
Unit1-Room2    2009-02-01 17:00:00.000 2009-02-01 19:30:00.000 
Unit1-Room2    2009-02-01 10:00:00.000 2009-02-01 15:00:00.000 
Unit1-Room2    2009-02-01 10:00:00.000 2009-02-01 15:00:00.000 
Unit1-Room2    2009-02-01 10:00:00.000 2009-02-01 15:00:00.000 
Unit1-Room1    2009-02-01 14:00:00.000 2009-02-01 16:30:00.000 
Unit1-Room1    2009-02-01 14:00:00.000 2009-02-01 16:30:00.000 
Unit1-Room1    2009-02-01 09:00:00.000 2009-02-01 13:00:00.000 
Unit1-Room1    2009-02-01 09:00:00.000 2009-02-01 13:00:00.000
```

dbName is the catagory field, MIN(dbStart) and MAX(dbEnd) fields are the high/low values for the series.The values are always for one day only.

How can I get the labels in the X_Axis to display just the time portion of the values?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ah haa!

1. Right click the X_Axis area and
   choose 'Axis properties...' from the
   context menu.
2. Click on 'Number' from the list to
   the left.
3. Select 'Custom' in the Category
   listbox.
4. type hh:mm (for am/pm) or HH:mm (for
   24 Hour) in the Custom format text
   box.
5. Click OK.